# Inspite of installing tensorflow, `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'` error occurs when I try to run files from CMD

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, cmd, pycharm

I am tring to execute code from 
https://github.com/bhavandar/leaf-diseases-predition
When I tried to execute the `run.py` file in cmd, I got the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nmule\Downloads\leaf-diseases-predition\app\gui.py", line 87, in Analyze
    self.hdf5Model()
  File "C:\Users\nmule\Downloads\leaf-diseases-predition\app\gui.py", line 146, in hdf5Model
    text = self.hdf5Processing(4)
  File "C:\Users\nmule\Downloads\leaf-diseases-predition\app\progress.py", line 53, in decorator
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\nmule\Downloads\leaf-diseases-predition\app\progress.py", line 39, in run
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nmule\Downloads\leaf-diseases-predition\app\gui.py", line 131, in hdf5Processing
    from hdf5.main import index
  File "C:\Users\nmule\Downloads\leaf-diseases-predition\hdf5\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow`

I have tensorflow installed and it appears when I check using `help('modules')`

I tried running the same file using pycharm. Tensorflow is installed and listed in my pycharm interpreter but I faced this issue:
https://github.com/bhavandar/leaf-diseases-predition/issues/2#issue-598447067

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Pycharm is that, it sth does not recognize the import option.
Try to reinstall tensorflow from pycharm terminal.
If it didn’t work, try to introduce a new venv for your project and install the requirements packages.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the `typing` library really was developed in Python 3.6. I was using 3.5 so it might have been missing a few classes.

**Update to python 3.6 or above and the problem should be solved.**

*In my case, I used python 3.7*

Answer (score 0):

I installed anaconda with environment of tensorflow, in pycharm you have that activate the environment that created.

Installation tensor-gpu / conda

https://www.thehardwareguy.co.uk/install-tensorflow-gpu

installation tensor / conda

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

steps

Run -> Debug Configurations -> Python interpreter (select your environment)